# Template type from a variable

Tags: c++, templates, interop

For an interface between Unity (C#) and a C++ plugin, I need the possibility to instantiate a class with two template parameters defined in Unity.
I cannot pass a C++ type directly so I'm instead using a `char` and a `switch` statement.

For a single parameter, it looks like this:

```
char type = 'I'; // For example; in practice, it is set from a Unity plugin call)

switch (type)
{
    case 'I':
    {
        ExtArrayExporter<int> * data_link = new ExtArrayExporter<int>(static_cast<int*>(external_array), ext_array_length);
        return(EXT_TYPES::RegisterNew(data_link));
    }
    case 'F':
    {
        ExtArrayExporter<float> * data_link = new ExtArrayExporter<float>(static_cast<float*>(external_array), ext_array_length);
        return(EXT_TYPES::RegisterNew(data_link));
    }
    case 'B':
    {
        ExtArrayExporter<bool> * data_link = new ExtArrayExporter<bool>(static_cast<bool*>(external_array), ext_array_length);
        return(EXT_TYPES::RegisterNew(data_link));
    }
}
```

**Question**:

How do I achieve this when `ExtArrayExporter` requires two types and I have two chars from Unity?

Trivial would be to have stacked `switch` statements but that grows quickly with more types to consider and is repetitive.

I hoped I could assign a type to a variable like to keep the method from above, but obviously this doesn't compile:

```
auto type_a = int;
```

Does C++ provide any smooth solution for this case?

Comment: Two types like `ExtArrayExporter<int, float>`? Wouldn't checking the two chars in `if` statement solve your problem i.e. `if ( type_a == 'I' && type_b == 'F' ) { ExtArrayExporter<int, float> ...; };`?

Comment: Are you trying to make your code look prettier, or are you trying to avoid explicitly writing out each template instantiation that you need? (Some nested template magic might work, but I don't see the details at the moment.)

Comment: @Azeem Yes exactly. Hm, I was fixated on the switch case construction which would have ended up with many code lines because I have 6 types I want to support. Just a bunch of Ifs is probably an acceptable solution.

Comment: @JaMiT The former. The template instantiations themselves seem expressive enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `ExtArrayExporter`, `EXT_TYPES`, etc., so I propose a generic code that you can adapt at your needs.

It's based on a recursive variadic template `foo()` function as follows

```
// ground case
template <typename ... Ts>
void foo ()
 { /* do something with Ts... */ }

// recursive case
template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Cs>
auto foo (char c0, Cs ... cs)
 {
   switch ( c0 )
    {
      case 'I':
         return foo<Ts..., int>(cs...);
         break;

      case 'F':
         return foo<Ts..., float>(cs...);
         break;

      case 'B':
         return foo<Ts..., bool>(cs...);
         break;

      // ...
    }
 }
```

and you can use it as follows

```
foo<>('I', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'I');
```

or also simply

```
foo('I', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'I');
```

The idea is that every call of `foo()` consume a `char` argument transforming it in a template argument and add it to the `Ts...` variadic list; when the char argument are ended (ground case) you can use the resolved `Ts...` template parameter.

Observe that this solution is generic and works non only for 2 but for an undefined number of arguments.

Comment: Why `break` after `return`? The `break` statements will never be reached.

Comment: @JaMiT - You could also ask: why `return`, when the ground case return `void`? If I write the code without `break`'s and, one day, I change it removing the `return`'s, I have to remember to add the `break`'s. And I'm not sure to remember this.